# SQL count DISTINCT ONCE user_id multiple attributes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello there I cant manage to get a good result for the following case:

I have a table which is like this:

```
UserID | Label
-------- ------
1      | Private
1      | Public
2      | Private
3      | Hidden
4      | Public
5      | Hidden
```

I want to have the following happening if a User has following assigned he is:

Private and Hidden are treaten the same: lets say Business
Public: BtoC
Public and Private and/or Hidden: both

So in the end I have a `count(DISTINCT UserID)` of

```
Business         3
BtoC             1
both             1
```

I have tried to use `CASE WHEN` but it doesn't work my current total query looks like this:

```
SELECT gen_month,
       count(DISTINCT cu.id) as leads,
        a.label
FROM generate_series(DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE::date - 96*INTERVAL '1 month'), CURRENT_DATE::date, '1 month') m(gen_month)
LEFT OUTER JOIN company_user AS cu
  ON (date_trunc('month', cu.creation_date) = date_trunc('month', gen_month))
LEFT JOIN user u
  ON u.user_id = cu.id
LEFT join user_account_status as uas
on cu.id = uas.user_id
LEFT JOIN account as a
on uas.account_id = a.id
where gen_month >= DATE_TRUNC('month',NOW() - INTERVAL '5 months')
group by  m.gen_month, a.label
order by gen_month
```

So my main problem now is that the count appears in every attribute once.
How can I make a userid only count once under condition CASE WHEN user_id appears Public and (Private or Hidden) THEN count(DISTINCT user_id) as Both?

Addition: its mySQL mariaDB and postgreSQL. But first I would happy with Postgres

Comment: Why `Business 3`? if i correct understand, UserID's 1,2,3,5 all are Business, so `count(DISTINCT UserID)` for Business should 4, not?

Comment: User 1 is Business and B2C, so he should be listed as Both.

Answer (score 0):

This is not implemented in your  total query, but for counting users for each category, you can:

```
with the_table(UserID , Label) as(
select 1      ,'Private' union all
select 1      ,'Public' union all
select 2      ,'Private' union all
select 3      ,'Hidden' union all
select 4      ,'Public' union all
select 5     ,'Hidden'  
)

select result, count(*) from (
    select UserID, case when min(Label) = 'Public' then 'BtoC' when max(Label) in('Private','Hidden') then 'Business' else 'both' end as result 
    from the_table
    group by UserID
) t
group by result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
  my_table(user_id, label) as (values
    (1,'Private'),
    (1,'Public'),
    (2,'Private'),
    (3,'Hidden'),
    (4,'Public'),
    (5,'Hidden')),
  t as (
    select
      user_id,
      string_agg('{'||label||'}', '') as labels
    from my_table
    group by user_id),
  tt as (
    select
      user_id,
      labels,
      case
        when
          position('{Public}' in labels) > 0 and (position('{Private}' in labels) > 0 or position('{Hidden}' in labels) > 0) then 'Both'
        when
          position('{Private}' in labels) > 0 or position('{Hidden}' in labels) > 0 then 'Business'
        when
          position('{Public}' in labels) > 0 then 'BtoC'
      end as kind
    from t)
select kind, count(*) from tt group by kind;
```

For MariaDB use `GROUP_CONCAT()` instead of PostgreSQL `string_agg()`.

Note that the `case` statement check conditions in order of appearance and returns the value for the first satisfied condition.

PS: Using PostgreSQL's arrays the conditions would be more elegant.